# Slack API chat.scheduleMessage everyday

Tags: api, bots, slack

I was wondering if there is a way to code a scheduling to post everyday a message in Slack. For now I have this, but it only run once

> https://slack.dev/bolt-js/tutorial/getting-started#listening-and-responding-to-a-message

> https://github.com/SlackAPI/bolt-js

> https://api.slack.com/tutorials/tags/glitch

> https://slack.dev/bolt-js/concepts#custom-routes

> https://github.com/slackapi/bolt-js/blob/main/README.md

```
// Require the Bolt package (github.com/slackapi/bolt)
const { App, subtype } = require('@slack/bolt');
const { WebClient } = require('@slack/web-api');
const axios = require('axios').default;

// Actions
(async () => {
  let currentDate = new Date();
  let futureDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + 3 * 60000);
  let unixTimeStamp = Math.floor(futureDate.getTime() / 1000);
  try {
    const USD = await axios.get(
      'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json'
    );

    const bitcoins = USD.data.bpi.USD.rate;

    console.log(unixTimeStamp);
    // Call chat.scheduleMessage with the built-in client
    const result = await web.chat.scheduleMessage({
      channel: general_channel,
      post_at: unixTimeStamp,
      text: `Summer has come and the Bitcoin is at ${bitcoins}`,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
})();
```

Comment: You want to look into setInterval() and set the interval to 24hr in second and have this process running 24/7

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this using the Slack APIs. You also would not want to give you need to fetched the Bitcoin conversion rate everyday before publish the Slack message. You should find a way to execute this using a corn job.